# Sharing css/javascript/images between different projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, resources

I can't seem to figure out the most efficient way to do this.

For example, I have some js files that are needed in both projects(within the same solution), how do I include them without duplicating the actual physical files, which I would rather not do? Same goes for images and css files.

I would also like to know what's the best way to generalize this for including the js resources in other solutions/projects.

VS really seems to be lacking an easy intuitive solution in this retrospect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you solve this? how?

Comment: [You can do this using Razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842988/mvc-razor-include-js-css-files-from-another-project), but I need it in the good old aspx/aspx.cs

Answer (score 1):

Why does it matter which project they are in?  All you really care about is where they get deployed on your web site, and what the path to them from the root of your site is, right?  So just pick a place to put them and have and code that refers to them use that path.

Comment: because I don't want to have projects that refer files in other projects, it seems unintuitive. I guess what you mean is to create a separate project for web resources only?

Comment: Yep, that might be the best way to do it.  Those files really aren't part of any project, because they aren't executed on the server.