# Asp.net MVC - load javascript from dll

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, load, .net-assembly

I'm embedding a javascript file as a resource in an assembly.
How do I load javascript file in Asp.Net MVC project?

Comment: You read the (entire) text and render it in your page.

Comment: Another way, Embed javascript to your assembly as a resource then you can use this as assembly reference. like this [assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("<full assemblyname>.<you javascriptfile.js>", "application/x-javascript")]

Comment: I'm read the article: link(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196727/Managing-Your-JavaScript-Library-in-ASP-NET). I want to load js file before render body in the _Layout.cshtml

Comment: I got the solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11848460)